# What Widget using on android this?

Tags: android

On Top-Rigt Button (add button), when click A new pop-up open?

I want make this action, what Widget I can use?
[On Top-Rigt Button (add button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEoQq.gif)

Comment: hmm it looks like a regular navigation Button in the action bar that opens a new fragment/activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely regular navigation. The pop-up you mention is achieved using fragment transitions. Check these websites for some examples and tutorials:

1. https://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html
2. http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/05/20/custom-animations-with-fragments/